# Python3 threading combining .start() doesn't create the join attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

This works fine:

```
def myfunc():
    print('inside myfunc')

t = threading.Thread(target=myfunc)
t.start()
t.join()
print('done')
```

However this, while apparently creating and executing the thread properly:

```
def myfunc():
    print('inside myfunc')

t = threading.Thread(target=myfunc).start()
t.join()
print('done')
```

Generates the following fatal error when it hits join():

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'

I would have thought that these statements are equivalent.  What is different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
t = threading.Thread(target=myfunc).start()
```

threading.Thread(target=myfunc) returns a thread object, However object.start() returns None. That's why there is an AttributeError.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.  I was thinking in terms of what each does as opposed to what each returns.

Comment: @FarNorth I hope you have the answer by now. Thread is a class in threading function and start is the function of that class. With threading.Thread, a object of class is being created, a call start() to call the start method, which actually starts the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.8 and the introduction of the *walrus* operator `:=`  you can use;

```
(t := threading.Thread(target=myfunc)).start()
```